# Dirmngr OCSP Responder Can't Load Trust CA Certificates

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, ocsp

I'm using dirmngr service on Ubuntu.
When running the service, I see the following errors in the log file:

```
    2015-09-29 09:37:45 dirmngr[25550.0] oops: ksba_cert_hash failed: No value
2015-09-29 09:37:45 dirmngr[25550.0] error loading certificate `/etc/dirmngr/trusted-certs/clientCA.crt': Invalid certificate object
2015-09-29 09:37:45 dirmngr[25550.0] oops: ksba_cert_hash failed: No value
2015-09-29 09:37:45 dirmngr[25550.0] error loading certificate `/etc/dirmngr/trusted-certs/client1.crt': Invalid certificate object
2015-09-29 09:37:45 dirmngr[25550.0] oops: ksba_cert_hash failed: No value
2015-09-29 09:37:45 dirmngr[25550.0] error loading certificate `/etc/dirmngr/trusted-certs/ca.crt': Invalid certificate object
2015-09-29 09:37:45 dirmngr[25550.0] oops: ksba_cert_hash failed: No value
2015-09-29 09:37:45 dirmngr[25550.0] error loading certificate `/etc/dirmngr/trusted-certs/trustca.crt': Invalid certificate object
2015-09-29 09:37:45 dirmngr[25550.0] oops: ksba_cert_hash failed: No value
2015-09-29 09:37:45 dirmngr[25550.0] error loading certificate `/etc/dirmngr/trusted-certs/udidlab_root_trust.crt': Invalid certificate object
2015-09-29 09:37:45 dirmngr[25550.0] permanently loaded certificates: 0
2015-09-29 09:37:45 dirmngr[25550.0]     runtime cached certificates: 0
```

Also, when running the daemon, here is the output:

```
root@ubuntu151:/etc/dirmngr/trusted-certs# dirmngr --allow-ocsp 
dirmngr[25773.0]: error opening `/root/.gnupg/dirmngr_ldapservers.conf': No such file or directory
dirmngr[25773.0]: permanently loaded certificates: 0
dirmngr[25773.0]:     runtime cached certificates: 0
# Home: ~/.gnupg
# Config: [none]
OK Dirmngr 1.1.1 at your service
```

Any idea why?

Thanks.